# Get property name and the type it expects from an object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

How can I get all the property names and the value type it expects from an object?

Suppose I have these 2 entity classes:

```
public class Blog 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string BloggerName { get; set;} 
    public Post Post { get; set; } 
} 

public class Post 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; } 
    public int BlogId { get; set; } 
    public Comment Comment { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I get this as the result:

- "Blog.Id expects an int"
- "Blog.Title expects a string"
- "Blog.BloggerName expects a string"
- "Post.Id expects an int"
- "Post.Title expects a string"
- "Post.DateCreated expects a string"
- etc...

I know this can be done one property at a time, but is there a more elegant way of doing this as the entity class has many properties (and they change from type as it is still in development) and has complex objects for which I want to do the same?

EDIT, this needs to be done recursively. Just passing `Blog` without knowing whether it contains another user defined object like `Post`, is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: A complex object is in this case user defined. Both `Blog` and `Post` are in this case complex objects (or user defined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use reflection of course.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(Blog).GetProperties())
{
    string propName = p.PropertyType.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("Property {0} expects {1} {2}",
        p.Name,
        "aeiou".Contains(char.ToLower(propName[0])) ? "an" : "a",
        propName);
}
```

Note that [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also has an overload which accepts a [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx), which allows you to get only some properties, e.g. instance/static public/private.

---

Below is an example of how this would theoretically work recursively, though even in this simple example, This creates a `StackOverflowException`, because `DateTime` has properties which themselves are `DateTime`s.

```
void ListProperties(Type t)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties())
    {
        string propName = p.PropertyType.Name;
        Console.WriteLine("Property {0} expects {1} {2}",
            p.Name,
            "aeiou".Contains(char.ToLower(propName[0])) ? "an" : "a",
            propName);
        ListProperties(p.PropertyType);
    }
}

ListProperties(typeof(Blog));
```

Comment: Proper grammar, nice one!

Comment: @Rotem, will this take the `Post` in the process too and it's properties with expected type?

Comment: @Quoter Do you mean that you'd like it to be recursive?

Comment: @Rotem, this code is not always correct. e.g. typeof (Dictionary<string, List<int>>).Name ==Dictionary`2

Comment: @Ash You could call `.ToString()` instead of `.Name`, that comes with the full namespace and the generic parameter types.

Comment: @Rotem, ToString() will be System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]]. i think, more readable result is expected :)

Comment: @ASh I leave it to the OP or to yourself to implement :)

Comment: @Rotem, do you have a recursive solution?

Comment: @Quoter This could be a recipe for disaster. Suppose that `Blog` has a property of type `Post` and `Post` had a property of type `Blog`, you would get a stackoverflowexception. It makes more sense to collect all the types in your assembly and list them all serially.

Comment: @Rotem, that won't happen as these classes are not ORM's. And I know that they don't have to be for this stackoverflowexception to happen, could happen to "normal" entity classes too. But I can assure you that there are no references from A to B and vice versa. That being said, how would your code look like for this to work recursively?

Comment: @Quoter This will happen on `DateTime` for example, as it has a lot of properties which themselves are `DateTime`. You'd need to start excluding recursion for types which you know are self-referencing. But if you want, just call the method from withing the method, as you normally due with recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection for this and do something like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void PrintAllProperties<T>(T type)
    {
        var t = type.GetType();
        var properties = t.GetProperties();

        Console.WriteLine("Listing all properties for type {0}", t);
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is of type: {1}", prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
Extensions.PrintAllProperties(new Blog());
Extensions.PrintAllProperties(new Post());
```

Comment: I think you meant `GetAllProperties<Blog>()` :)

Comment: Maybe should be `ListAllProperties` or `PrintAllProperties`. `Get` assumes getting something back.

Comment: @Rotem - adjusted ... Jeff, GetAllProperties<Blog>() wouldn't work.

Comment: @DarrenDavies It works well. Just as an aside, a non-generic `PrintAllProperties(object o)` would work just as well in this case.

Comment: @Rotem - you would have to use:  `Extensions.GetAllProperties<Standard>(new Standard());`

And if you have ReSharper it suggests a refactor to `Extensions.GetAllProperties(new Standard());` which is what I provided.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I'm not sure what you mean. Assuming `public static void PrintAllProperties(object o) { }`, you can call it as `PrintAllProperties(new Standard())`, no? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rotem - no, you've misunderstood.  `PrintAllProperties(new Standard())` is correct and is what I've provided in my answer.  Jeff stated you can do it as `GetAllProperties<Blog>()` which is not valid.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I understand, I simply commented that your method does not have to be generic at all.